# Can I parse a GML Surface from a DOM node in Geotools?

Tags: dom, geotools

I have a set of small XML documents - AIXM, to be specific - that contain deep within them GML elements.  For instance:

```
<hasMember>
  <Airspace xmlns="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.0" gml:id="Airspace1">
    <identifier xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" codeSpace="http://www.faa.gov/nasr">d1c1e508-4a4d-4d52-8c11-c851c6dd7600</identifier>
    <timeSlice>
      <AirspaceTimeSlice gml:id="Airspace1_TS1">
          [...]
        <designator>P51</designator>
        <name>P-51 BANGOR, WA</name>
        <geometryComponent>
          <AirspaceGeometryComponent>
            <operation>BASE</operation>
            <operationSequence>1</operationSequence>
            <theAirspaceVolume>
              <AirspaceVolume>
                <upperLimit uom="FT">02499</upperLimit>
                <upperLimitReference>MSL</upperLimitReference>
                <lowerLimit uom="FT">GND</lowerLimit>
                <lowerLimitReference>SFC</lowerLimitReference>
                <horizontalProjection>
                  <Surface gml:id="Surface1" srsDimension="2" srsName="URN:OGC:DEF:CRS:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
                    <patches xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
                      <PolygonPatch xmlns:ns="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
                            [...]
```

and on for a ways.

My current application has loaded the document with a DOM parser and extracted the data I need from the XML Document.  Now I need to pull out the GML  element from the selected DOM Node, hasMember/Airspace/timeSlice/AirspaceTimeSlice/geometryComponent/AirspaceGeometryComponent/.

Can I accomplish that with Geotools?  DOMParser insists on starting at the root Document node.  The only alternative I can spot is SurfaceTypeBinding.parse(), which accepts a Node ... but I can't puzzle out how to call it.

Comment: I'd probably grab the node and put it in a new Root node (maybe a WFS one) and see if that fools the parser. It should be able to handle it in that case.

Comment: Sounds like a good possibility.  I'll give that a try and let you know what happens.